# Beautiful soup, intersection of two lists (one with pairs of strings)

Tags: python, html, list, beautifulsoup, intersection

I'm using beautifulSoup to **scrape** several urls.

BeautifulSoup returns a list of results that looks like this:

`list1 = ['url1','keyword1', 'url2', 'keyword2'...]` (pairs of keywords and the urls where they come from)

I want to match `list1` against `list2`, a list of keywords of reference.

My goal being that if `keyword_referenceX` from `list2` is present in `list1` as well, I get as a result like `['urlX', keyword_referenceX']`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = []
list1 = []
results = []

urls = ['url1','url2']

list2  = ['keyword_reference1', 'keyword_reference2']

for url in urls:
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
    
    for sub_heading in soup.find_all('h3'): 
        if  str(1) + ". " in sub_heading.text and "11." not in sub_heading.text: #filter I apply  
            list1.append(url)
            list1.append(sub_heading.text)
                
for list2_element in list2:
    for list1_element in list1:
        if list2_element in list1_element:
            results.append(list2_element)


print(results)
```

Comment: why not use a dict instead of list for `list1`

Comment: From what I understand a dictionary is not the right approach see details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61374655/adding-values-to-dictionary-in-for-loop-updating-instead-of-appending/61375223#61375223

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import defaultdict

urls = []
list1 = defaultdict(list)
results = []

urls = ['url1','url2']

list2  = ['keyword_reference1', 'keyword_reference2']

for url in urls:
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")

    for sub_heading in soup.find_all('h3'): 
        if  str(1) + ". " in sub_heading.text and "11." not in sub_heading.text: 
            # list1 is actually a defaultdict
            list1[url].append(sub_heading.text)

for list2_element in list2:
    for k, v in list1.items():
      # Here v is the list containing sub_heading.text and k is the url
      if list2_element in v:
        results.extend([url, list2_element])


print(results)
```